# how to create complex nested json objects from values in database using python

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a json object that would look like below:

```
{
  "Accounts": [
    ***"<SOMETHING_FROM_DATABASE>"***: {
      "Rules": [
        ***"<SOMETHING_FROM_DATABASE>"***:{
          "Compliant":[],
          "Non-Complaint":[],
          "INSUFFICIENT_DATA":[]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue that I am having is that the names of some of the keys will be pulled from a database.

I have tried every suggestion that I could find but nothing is pointing me towards a clear direction. I am sure I am not the first person who wants to create a json object from values stored in database! Any help is appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: What type of database? Have you started to make code for pulling values from your database? If so, post that code as well. If you are having problems, we can't help unless we can see what you have accomplished thus far.

Comment: Hi Evan, to be specific the data is coming as a dictionary object as a result of calling: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.describe_compliance_by_config_rule. There is a loop that goes through and grabs all non-compliant resources, creates a json object and then dumps it in a bucket on AWS. I however, do not see the value of confusing you with the logic of the entire code here. The ask is how to create nested json objects with the above format. if it helps, disregard the database and assume the values are stored in variable.